# Printing multiple labels in one print job

Tags: javascript, dymo

I am using the Dymo JS SDK from [here](http://developers.dymo.com) to print some labels to a label printer. I have an API which returns an array of strings, and each string contains the XML for a label to be printed. At the moment, in order to print these labels, I have the following:

```
$.get('print_shipping_labels.html', {shippingJobId: jobId}, function(data, status) {
  var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
  if (printers.length === 0) {
    // throw error
  }

  data.forEach(labelXml => {
    var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);
    label.print(printers[0].name);
  });
});
```

which works, however if the API returns 12 labels, when I go to print, it creates 12 separate print jobs rather than one print job with 12 'pages'. I know this is possible because I was able to do it with the java.awt.print.Book class, but that is no longer a viable option.

I'm aware that there are examples of printing multiple labels using the LabelSetBuilder class, but all the examples I have seen assume you are using a template XML to substitute your own values into. I don't want to do that, I want to print my XML as is.